# JWT - storing token in cookies

Tags: jwt, express-jwt

I understand there are many differences / pro's and cons of storing the token as a cookie vs using localStorage. This question is an ask on the actual implementation of storing it in a cookie.

I'm confused, because if the token is stored inside a cookie, the user will always be validated, making the use of a token worthless. The token will always be associated with the server side session data.

Can someone explain the implementation details?

Comment: One of the uses of JWTs is to remove server-side session data.  I think your question is a little broad at the moment and you might look into including more specifics of what you are wanting to do.

Comment: I started out wanting to store the token client side, but I came across this article. The problem is the implementation is vague and i don't understand how storing it in a cookie a altogether different from just using a plain old cookie - https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Answer (score 2):

Example:

(1) plain old cookie: Data in your "old plain cookie": "129scdsdf23i"

(2) JWT token: JWT data/token which is saved in the cookie: "1122abde"

How do you verity the data/token is a "valid authentication":

(1) plain old cookie: compare "129scdsdf23i" with data saved in database/server, check if they are the "identical"

(2) JWT token: step a: VERIFY "1122abde", "1122abde" itself is valid because (1 + 2 + a )= d and (1+2+b) = e. This is just an example.

step b: DECODE "1122abde" to "{user: user1, email: "user1@gmail.com"}", as you can see, now you get the user and email.

So "1122abde" is created by sever and a secret random number is involved during the creation. A hacker can never create a valid JWT token without knowing the "secret".

> "I'm confused, because if the token is stored inside a cookie, the user will always be validated, making the use of a token worthless."

=> cookie is just a place to save your data, it has nothing to do with your data itself. If you have "1x22abde" in the cookie, it is a bad token which will fail the authentication.